# How to convert XAML(ControlTemplate) to Code-Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, devexpress

```
<dxg:LookUpEdit Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    DisplayMember="Name" 
                    AutoPopulateColumns="False">
    <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <dxg:GridControl Name="PART_GridControl">
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name"/>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Date"/>
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
</dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

please help me, I do not know how to add `GridColumn` on `GridControl` and set `LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate = GridControl`

Thank you very much. I think XAMLREADER can help me, I'm stuck here

```cs
ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory gridcontrol = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(GridControl));
FrameworkElementFactory gridcolumn = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(GridColumn));
gridcontrol.SetValue(?, ?);
gridcolumn.SetValue(?, ?);
ct.VisualTree = gridcontrol;
```

Comment: seems like you've unaccepted the answer. is there anything else I may help you with?

Comment: I still want to see any value in the gridcontrol.SetValue(?, ?); gridcolumn.SetValue(?, ?); , it makes me headache

Answer (score 3):

creating control/data templates in code behind involves factory classes, that may be more complicated for non framework types.

example from [Creating a control template with code behind](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddb7fd77-dea1-40f5-a5b7-30d35ecda70e/creating-a-control-template-with-code-behind?forum=wpf)

```cs
ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ListBoxItem));
FrameworkElementFactory elemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
elemFactory.Name = "Border";
elemFactory.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(5));
elemFactory.SetValue(Border.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(1));
elemFactory.SetValue(Border.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, true);
template.VisualTree = elemFactory;

//same can be used as 
LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate = template;
```

above is just an example, you may need to use the appropriate types

alternatively keeping the control templates in resource dictionary may help you

or the easiest solution is to parse the xaml in code behind

```cs
const string xaml = "<ControlTemplate><dxg:GridControl Name=""PART_GridControl""><dxg:GridControl.Columns><dxg:GridColumn FieldName=""Name""/><dxg:GridColumn FieldName=""Date""/></dxg:GridControl.Columns></dxg:GridControl></ControlTemplate>";
ControlTemplate template = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as ControlTemplate;

//this can be used as 
LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate = template;
```